# KVM Live or Near-Live Migration from LVM to filesystem backend

Tags: kvm-virtualization, migration, live-migration

My guest machine has 2 partitions (80GB + 1TB). Both of them is on LVM. I want to transfer all disks to another machine with minimum downtime. I transferred another machine with nc. It takes 4 days and during transfer my VM was off.

I tried to make snapshot after then transfer dirty pages. But AFAIK with LVM its'not possible. My target machine has no LVM setup and free unpartitioned space. So on target machine disks must be raw file images.

```
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
  <source dev='/dev/vg-datastore/lv-vm-1138'/>
  <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
</disk>
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
  <source dev='/dev/vg-datastore-sata/lv-vm-1138-2'/>
  <target dev='vdb' bus='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>
</disk>
```

Source Host:

- CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU D-1520 @ 2.20GHz
- OS: 16.04.1 LTS
- Kernel: 4.2.0-34-generic
- qemu-kvm: 1:2.3+dfsg-5ubuntu9.2
- QEMU: 2.3.0
- libvirt: 1.2.16

Target Host:

- CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU D-1520 @ 2.20GHz
- OS: 16.04 LTS
- Kernel: 4.4.0-28-generic
- qemu-kvm: 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.2
- QEMU: 2.5.0
- libvirt: 1.3.1

Comment: Please add source & destination OS, KVM and libvirt version.

Comment: While qemu and libvirt do support live migration with storage, it sounds like you have a huge disk volume there. If the VM is active and the network between the two hosts isn't very fast, such a migration might never converge. 

Not to mention the version difference there, and you haven't mentioned the CPU types on the hosts and in the guest

Comment: I updated question with CPU info and partition sizes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

KVM/libvirt supports VM live migration with storage migration (a shared-nothing setup), albeit with some limitation. Your main problem is that storage pools have different configuration, so I am not sure `libvirt` will migrate the VM image without problem.

The command to do a live migration + storage copy is:

```
virsh migrate  --live --copy-storage-all --persistent qemu+ssh://root@/system
```

This command presumes you have a valid libvirt-based connection to the remote host.

If you have problems migrating your virtual disks, you can try to create stub destination virtual disk files with executing (on the destination host) something similar to `fallocate /dev/vg-datastore/lv-vm-1138 -l 80G` and `/dev/vg-datastore-sata/lv-vm-1138-2 -l 1T`.

Anyway, due to differences between hosts, this can be a bumpy road.

A simpler way to migrate your VM images is to use an incremental disk copy approach, using [`blocksync`](https://gist.github.com/shodanshok/b35875e9baabe01f6dda315259d9046c). In short:

- when the VM is running, do a first copy of the virtual disks to the destination host. This first copy **will** be incoherent and unreliable, but will work as a "seed" for the next copy;
- at appropriate time, shutdown the VM and execute a **second copy** of the virtual disks. This second copy will transfer the changed blocks only and it will be much faster than the first one;
- when finished, define the virtual domain and start the VM on the destination host.

Please note that the linked `blocksync` program is a personal forked version based on [this original script](https://gist.github.com/rcoup/1338263) (which, by the way, is a improved version of [this script](https://www.bouncybouncy.net/programs/blocksync.py)). I obviously assume **NO RESPONSIBILITY** for the code and I strongly suggest you to **thoroughly test it** before using it on production virtual machines/disk files. As always, you **MUST** have a confirmed-good backup before doing anything.

**EDIT:** as suggested in the comment below, another great software to synchronize a block device/virtual image file is [`bdsync`](https://github.com/TargetHolding/bdsync). The approach is basically the same: take a first "seed" copy of the disk file while the VM is running, then stop the VM and do another final copy. In the past I even asked `bdsync` developer about a similar question; [see here for more information](https://github.com/TargetHolding/bdsync/issues/13).

Comment: Have you seen [bdsync](https://github.com/TargetHolding/bdsync)?

Comment: Sure - I even [contributed with patches](https://github.com/TargetHolding/bdsync/pull/12). It is a very good piece of software and it has very good performance, but on some circumstances the "diff-then-patch" approach can be a little tedious. On the other hand `blocksync` use a direct-write approach and, being written in python, is quite simple to extend (but also somewhat slower than `bdsync`). Anyway, I will edit my answer to include references to `bdsync`.